# Máximo valor que depende de otro parametro

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, oracle

Buena tarde, tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT e.NUMDOCUMENTO AS "NUM. DOCUMENTO",e.NOMBRE1||' '||TRIM(e.NOMBRE2)||' '||e.APELLIDO1||' '||e.APELLIDO2 "NOMBRE",fe.FECHAAFILIACION,ft.FONDOTIPO,t.TERCERO
FROM EMPLEADO e,VINCULACION v,VINCULACIONDET vd,FONDOXEMPLEADO fe,FONDOTIPO ft,Terceros t
WHERE e.CODEMPLEADO = v.CODEMPLEADO AND v.NUMVINCULACION = vd.NUMVINCULACION AND vd.TIPOREG = 2 AND v.CODVINCULACIONESTADO = 1 AND e.CODEMPLEADO = fe.CODEMPLEADO AND fe.CODFONDOTIPO = ft.CODFONDOTIPO AND fe.CODFONDO = t.CODTERCERO AND fe.FECHAAFILIACION = (SELECT MAX(fe2.FECHAAFILIACION) FROM FONDOXEMPLEADO_TPP fe2 WHERE e.CODEMPLEADO = fe2.CODEMPLEADO)  
ORDER BY e.CODEMPLEADO ASC
```

Lo que me trae el siguiente resultado:

```
2589645 ;PEDRO PEREZ ;10/24/2014 00:00:00 ;Salud ;1 ;Coopsalud
2589645 ;PEDRO PEREZ ;01/01/2016 00:00:00 ;Cesantias ;9 ;Ahoro seguro
2589645 ;PEDRO PEREZ ;10/24/2014 00:00:00 ;Caja de Compensacion Familiar ;5 ;Familia integral
2589645 ;PEDRO PEREZ ;10/24/2014 00:00:00 ;Cesantias ;9 ;Servingreso 
2589645 ;PEDRO PEREZ ;10/24/2014 00:00:00 ;Pension ;2 ;Servingreso
```

la situación que quiero solucionar es la siguiente:

```
2589645 ;PEDRO PEREZ ;01/01/2016 00:00:00 ;Cesantias ;9 ;Ahoro seguro
2589645 ;PEDRO PEREZ ;10/24/2014 00:00:00 ;Cesantias ;9 ;Servingreso
```

necesito que la consulta traiga del mismo tipo (ejemplo el 9) el registro con la fecha mas alta que en esta caso seria:

```
2589645 ;PEDRO PEREZ ;01/01/2016 00:00:00 ;Cesantias ;9 ;Ahoro seguro
```

por lo que el resultado final sería:

```
2589645 ;PEDRO PEREZ ;10/24/2014 00:00:00 ;Salud ;1 ;Coopsalud
2589645 ;PEDRO PEREZ ;01/01/2016 00:00:00 ;Cesantias ;9 ;Ahoro seguro
2589645 ;PEDRO PEREZ ;10/24/2014 00:00:00 ;Caja de Compensacion Familiar ;5 ;Familia integral
2589645 ;PEDRO PEREZ ;10/24/2014 00:00:00 ;Pension ;2 ;Servingreso
```

estaba intentando seleccionar la máxima fecha con:

```
WHERE e.CODEMPLEADO = v.CODEMPLEADO AND v.NUMVINCULACION = vd.NUMVINCULACION AND vd.TIPOREG = 2 AND v.CODVINCULACIONESTADO = 1 AND e.CODEMPLEADO = fe.CODEMPLEADO AND fe.CODFONDOTIPO = ft.CODFONDOTIPO AND fe.CODFONDO = t.CODTERCERO AND fe.FECHAAFILIACION = (SELECT MAX(fe2.FECHAAFILIACION) FROM FONDOXEMPLEADO fe2 WHERE e.CODEMPLEADO = fe2.CODEMPLEADO)
```

pero de los 6 registros sólo queda:

```
2589645 ;PEDRO PEREZ ;01/01/2016 00:00:00 ;Cesantias ;9 ;Ahoro seguro
```

Comment: a ver priemero que nada el campo date si quieres que tome el ultimo tendrias que hacer un MAX(Campo) adicional si quieres que lo agrupe por ft.FONDOTIPO debes utilizar el group by ft.FONDOTIPO

Comment: creo que necesita un distinct(id), max(valor) y seria casi igual al select que te explica @FranciscoNúñez

Comment: @JackNavaRow como seria?

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez mmm como seria?

Answer (score 0):

No me queda claro si la consulta es sobre `mysql` o `oracle`, sin embargo entiendo que funcionaría en ambos. Lo ideal, además, es que aportes más información del modelo de datos, tablas y campos solo la consulta puede ser insuficiente, sin embargo con las muestras de datos que aportas se puede deducir una solución.

En primer lugar reformatee algo tu código, principalmente por el uso explicito de los `JOIN`, en lo personal me resulta mucho más claro de entender y si bien no hay diferencias en performance son sentencias más seguras ya que encaso de falta (por error) de la sentencia `ON` no funcionaría, en cambio con un `JOIN` implícito   corremos riesgo de generar un producto cartesiano entre tablas. En definitiva mi propuesta pasa por definir un `JOIN` con una subconsulta por `FONDOXEMPLEADO` agrupando por `CODEMPLEADO`, `CODFONDO` y `CODFONDOTIPO` y recuperando `MAX(FECHAAFILIACION)`, esto funcionará correctamente siempre que se repita `CODEMPLEADO`, `CODFONDO` y `CODFONDOTIPO` pero no exista repetición en `FECHAAFILIACION`, lo ideal es que existiera un `ID` único en `FONDOXEMPLEADO` y el `MAX()` hacerlo sobre este campo.

```
SELECT  e.NUMDOCUMENTO AS "NUM. DOCUMENTO",
    e.NOMBRE1||' '||TRIM(e.NOMBRE2)||' '||e.APELLIDO1||' '||e.APELLIDO2 "NOMBRE",
    fe.FECHAAFILIACION,
    ft.FONDOTIPO,
    t.TERCERO
    FROM EMPLEADO e
    INNER JOIN VINCULACION v
        ON e.CODEMPLEADO = v.CODEMPLEADO
        AND v.CODVINCULACIONESTADO = 1 
    INNER JOIN VINCULACIONDET vd
        ON v.NUMVINCULACION = vd.NUMVINCULACION
        AND vd.TIPOREG = 2 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT CODEMPLEADO,
                       CODFONDO,
                       CODFONDOTIPO,
                       MAX(FECHAAFILIACION) AS "FECHAAFILIACION"
            FROM FONDOXEMPLEADO
            GROUP BY CODEMPLEADO, CODFONDO, CODFONDOTIPO
        ) fe
        ON e.CODEMPLEADO = fe.CODEMPLEADO
    INNER JOIN FONDOTIPO ft
        ON fe.CODFONDOTIPO = ft.CODFONDOTIPO 
    INNER JOIN Terceros t
        ON fe.CODFONDO = t.CODTERCERO
    ORDER BY e.CODEMPLEADO ASC
```

Espero te sea útil.